# How to ensure precedence of files over directories with Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

My httpd.conf uses the MultiViews option to serve HTML files for URLs like http://server/blog. This works fine, unless there are directories with the same name – Apache will then try to serve the directory.

Is there any way to ensure precedence of blog.html over blog/, or rather: can I make Apache process content negotiation according to MultiView although a matching entity (the directory) is present?

In nginx, I can do this explicitly:

```
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I retreated to using mod_rewrite. The following rule rewrites URLs without a dot (".") only, so /images/image.jpeg is left alone:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```